# Angular App clear user browser cache programmatically‏

Tags: angularjs, browser-cache

Is there any way, I can clear the views and scripts that are cached in user browser after some interval (eg: after 2 hrs) so that they don't need to clear their cache manually. I think, it's something that application may require when there some changes made on production but user don't see those updates until they clear their browser cache. Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to involve the server, but at the end of every one of your scripts/partials/css attach a datetime that only updates every 2 hours (or whatever interval you want)

So to include angular it would be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../angular.js?12345"></script>
```

Then an hour later your server would change the time to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../angular.js?12346"></script>
```

Or however you want to do it, this will force the user to go get the new data.

Comment: Thank you very much. So that means, there will be a separate api end point that will only return datetime during the time wen angular app loads up?